# How to fix basic trigger not triggered in SQL Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, sql-update

I've been trying to get this trigger to work but for some reason it does not even activate before I update/insert things in the table. The aim of this trigger (and I'm required to do this through triggers) is to ensure that all entries in the DISCS table have either 'L' or 'S' in the FORMAT attribute. If not, the entry should not be inserted/updated.

I've tried to add a line to check if the trigger was being activated at all (the "buenos dias" line) but it seems it isn't for some reason. I'm just a beginner with triggers and I'm sure the error is really dumb but I just can't find it.

The code for the trigger is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER FORMAT_T
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF FORMAT
  ON DISCS
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  bad_format EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Buenos dias.');
  IF :NEW.FORMAT != 'S' AND :NEW.FORMAT != 'L' THEN
    RAISE bad_format;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN bad_format THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Bad format, could not insert/update.');
END FORMAT_T;
```

Once I compile the trigger without problems, I try to update the following row (using the ID of the first row just to be able to test it easily):

```
UPDATE DISCS
SET FORMAT = 'W'
WHERE ID = 1;
```

This should return an error since the format I'm updating it to is not 'L' nor 'S', but instead the row is just updated without problems and without the "buenos dias" line even popping up. There are no errors in the user_errors table either.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: A debug message won't stop a value being entered. Probably it should raise an exception.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson what will stop the value from being entered is the exception 'bad_format', not the debug message. Technically that exception will stop it from being entered

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your trigger code as posted works just fine. The real problem is revealed by this:

> without the "buenos dias" line even popping up

Clearly you're running in an environment in which DBMS_OUTPUT is disabled. So the UPDATE fails as expected, you just don't see the message. We can demonstrate this easily by removing the EXCEPTION block from your trigger code, as this [SQL Fiddle demonstrates](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8b8b8/1).

Enabling DBMS_OUTPUT depends on your execution environment. In SQL*Plus run `set serveroutput on`. In Oracle SQL Developer choose <kbd>View</kbd> > <kbd>Dbms_Output</kbd> and set the connection. In PL/SQL Developer enable DBMS_OUTPUT on the SQL worksheet. And so on.

---

Incidentally, a trigger is the wrong way to enforce this rule. The correct approach is to define a check constraint on the column.

```
alter table disks add constraint disc_format_ck 
    check (format in ('S', 'L'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is related with

`IF :NEW.FORMAT != 'S' AND :NEW.FORMAT != 'L' THEN`

statement

Just replace with

`IF :NEW.FORMAT not in ('S','L') THEN`

but, I'd prefer using a check constraint :

```
ALTER TABLE discs
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_format CHECK (format in ('S','L'))
```

In this case Database automatically hurls *"the check constraint is violated"* when characters other than `'S'` or `'L'` entered , without need of a trigger.

Comment: I used `AND` since the condition for the exception to be raised is that the format does not match S nor L, that is, both inequalities are met. If I use `OR` the trigger will ALWAYS throw an exception. The thing is, the trigger doesn't even activate (the "buenos dias" line is not printed). I've tried making these changes but the trigger doesn't do anything either way. Also I am required by the assignment to do this with triggers, so I can't use constraints.

Comment: @alestarbucks no, `:NEW.FORMAT != 'S' OR :NEW.FORMAT != 'L'` equals `NOT(:NEW.FORMAT = 'S' AND :NEW.FORMAT = 'L')` like in Symbolic Logic or common factor for addition/subtraction in Maths.

Comment: alright, thanks for that, I'll update that part of the code. However, the trigger is still not activated: the test line does not pop up and the row is updated without any problems without showing the exception.

Comment: @alestarbucks OK, edited. Using `not in` is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER FORMAT_T
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
OF FORMAT
ON DISCS
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
  IF :NEW.FORMAT not in( 'S' , 'L') THEN    
    raise_application_error(-20010,'Bad format, could not insert/update.');
  END IF;   
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('OTHERS EXCEPTION');   
END FORMAT_T;
```

Answer (score 0):

USE raise_application_error:

raise_application_error(-20010,'Bad format, could not insert/update.');

Answer (score 0):

You need to set server output in on state for executing trigger. For that you type the following command in your sql plus

```
set serveroutput on
```